# Height of garage with planning or without planning

Tags: garage, planning

Currently replacing a garage and seeking clarification on the maximum eaves height of 2.5m without planning.

As it stand my eaves will be 2.65m at front elevation (rear is higher as the land slopes away from house). Interior wall height 2.4m with a one block course of block for damp course.

Would you advise to lower the interior height or apply for retrospective planning?

If planning applied for what is the then maximum height of the eaves?

Thanks,

Ben

Comment: Max height will be what they permit...

Comment: Any experience with it? I’m pretty confident with it literally being 150mm over any planning application would be fine

Comment: So many factors, such as other people’s views etc etc... apply and find out, or go in and talk to them.